# Weird animation queue

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, chaining

I've been playing around with chained animations, and this has baffled me quite a lot

I have just one element being animated, but the 'shake' effect is left to the bottom of the queue.

```
.animate().animate().effect('shake',{times:3},10).animate()....
```

online simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/ottoln/F9xfD/3/

can't quite understand why...anyone?

*the fiddle he probably meant to link:* http://jsfiddle.net/ottoln/F9xfD/

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct fiddle? I can't find the `.effect()`

Comment: that's how animation chaining works in jQuery, isn't it? The second `animate()` will run after the first has finished.

Comment: Describe what you were expecting instead. We cannot determine from your code: all we know from your code is what _does_ happen. And there is no `effect()` in your testcase.

Comment: added another fiddle to the question, he probably meant to include that one

Comment: I _think_ what's going on here is that the effect happens after the last animate even though it is written before that. i.e. the ball shakes when it's at the bottom but it should shake when it's at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a [promise() & done()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) in there, to make sure that the `fx` is fully resolved before continuing your animation:

```
$('#bunda').animate({
    marginTop: '+=200',
    marginLeft: '+=150'
}, 1300).animate({
    marginTop: '-50',
    marginLeft: '+=100',
    'background-color': 'darkred'
}, 1000).effect('shake', {
    times: 3
}, 50).promise().done(function(){
 $(this).animate({
    marginTop: '+=300'
}, 500);   
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/MtkaY/

Comment: Thanks guys.

@configurator: so 'effect()' is actually working on a different queue, rather than fx?

@Niklas: Thanks for promised().done(), I did not know those methods. It's just a bit annoying that you have to be using anonymous functions all the time in the callbacks...it makes the code look very ugly.

@tomalak-geretkal: Sorry dude, I posted the wrong jsfiddle version. 
Right one should have been: http://jsfiddle.net/ottoln/F9xfD/


cheers


Otto

Answer (score 0):

The `effect` method doesn't queue up exactly like the rest of the animate calls, but it takes a callback as a parameter which would be run after the effect is finished. You can do this instead:

```
$('#bunda').animate({
    marginTop: '+=200',
    marginLeft: '+=150'
}, 1300).animate({
    marginTop: '-=50',
    marginLeft: '+=100',
    'background-color': 'darkred'
}, 1000).effect('shake', {
    times: 3,
}, 50, function () {
    $('#bunda').animate({
        marginTop: '+=300'
    }, 500);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CCw9U/